# FORTRAN self-launching MPI program

Tags: ssh, fortran, cluster-computing, mpi

Is there any way to call mprirun inside FORTRAN program? I'm working on public linux cluster via ssh and the main idea is to automatically enqueue program after its execution is over.

I tried to write something like this at the end of the program:

```
CALL system('mpirun -np 16 -maxtime 100 TestNP')
```

But recieved this error:

```
sh: mpirun: command not found
```

Any ideas ?

Comment: So try prefixing `mpirun` in your call to `system` with the absolute path to `mpirun` on your system -- if you don't know what that is look at the results of `which mpirun` at the command line.  I'm a little puzzled about why you are trying to do this, do you really want to (re-)submit the program when it finishes ?  (and, of course, re-submit it *ad infinitum*)

Comment: Yes , i'm dealing with long term hydrodynamics simulations, so program should be executed many times ( becouse of the schedule on cluster you cannot launch long time calcultions involving many processes ). So after one iteration is over, data is saved for next launch. Now i am making launches manually, but it is absolutely inconvenient.

Comment: I think I understand what you are trying to do, but I still wouldn't use a call to `system` to do it.  What I would do depends on information you haven't given us, such as what job management system your cluster provides.

Comment: Unfortunately i don't know much about how actually cluster manages queued jobs. To enqueue my job i use mpirun command in putty console. After that cluster automatically enqueues my program, and executes it than sufficient resourses are available.

Comment: You're time would be better spent, I suggest, learning how to configure and manage long running jobs on your cluster than on trying to create a program which re-runs itself using a call to the `system` routine.

Comment: I guess you right. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the missing path prefix, so specifying an absolute path for mpirun should help. However there are several problems with your approach:

- If every MPI process executes it, you would have too many instances running, so only one of the nodes (e.g. the master node) should execute it.
- The original program won't be finished, until the one called via the system() call did not finish. So, if your queue is wall-clock limited, you don't gain anything at all.

Typically, tasks like this are done via shell-scripts. E.g. in Bash you would write something like:

```
while true; do
  mpirun your_program
done
```

This would re-invoke mpirun continuously until not killed by you or the queuing system. (So *be careful* with it!)